# Failed to insert into MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Right, im just doing a little bit of testing before building my project and i keep getting errors. I'm using WAMP and phpmyadmin for the database.

I have managed to connect to the database successfully, but cannot seem to insert data into the table.

Ultimately i want to insert data the user uploads from a form but I'm using static figures for now to get the INSERT working correctly.

So when the user clicks submit, i want this to run;

**PHP/MYSQL:**

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "#########");//I have hashed out the password here
define("DB_NAME", "uploads");

// 1. Create a database connection
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
// Test if connection succeeded
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . 
       mysqli_connect_error() . 
       " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
  );
}


    $query =  "INSERT INTO ";
    $query .= "customers "; 
    $query .= "(`reference`, `doc1`, `doc2`, `doc3`) ";
    $query .= "VALUES ('123456', 'newimage1.jpg', 'newimage2.jpg', 'newimage3.jpg')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if ($result) {
      echo "created insert";
    } else {
      // Failure
      echo "failed to insert";
    }
```

Okay so the database connection works as it throws no errors, however i just get "failed to insert".

Any ideas guys? if you need more info just post a comment

**EDIT:**

echo the $query i get:

INSERT INTO customers(`reference`, `doc1`, `doc2`, `doc3`) VALUES ('123456', 'newimage1.jpg', 'newimage2.jpg', 'newimage3.jpg')failed to insert

and its the same if i remove the space on customers

[image]

**WORKING:**

The fields where varchar 11, and the text was too long to be inserted. Very stupid mistake haha, relatively new to using MYSQL with php. But thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you echo `$query` for us and add it to this post?

Comment: Use `mysqli_error` to check the happening error.

Comment: mysqli_error on what sorry?

Comment: what are your mysql table fields? is reference INT and doc1-3 varchar? how long are they? use phpmyadmin and execute the query from there.

Comment: RTFM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @matthewsmart share your table structure `desc customers `

Comment: At least `newimage1.jpg` is not 11 symbols

Comment: When you say use mysqli_error , do you mean like so:  echo mysqli_error($result);

Comment: Well, you was at my level once, everyone has to learn at some point and that's what I'm doing. I have limited time to learn and don't need negative people like you criticizing a question that may be easy for you....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question there is a mistake in you table structure change the `varchar` size (increase more than 11 )to insert data int table for column `doc1` `doc2` `doc3`